# How to request something from model using JavaScript variable in cshtml-file? (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need to use JS variable to request particular item from array that stored in model. How to do this?

Here's a code sample:

```
function CreateCategoryList() 
    {
        var limit = @(Model.CategoriesCount.ToString());

        for (i=0; i<limit; i++)
        {
            var category = '<div class="CategoryItem">' + '@(Model.CategoryList[i].Name.ToString())' + '</div>';                
            $("#CategoriesPopup").append(category);
        }
        alert($(".CategoryItem:first").text());
    }
```

I need to get access to i-th item in Model.CategoryList using i variable in for loop.

Comment: Please elaborate ur question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor is not executed on the client side, so your code sample above is invalid.

Easiest solution is to store the entire array as a client side Javascript variable, using serialization. I have used Json.NET in the example below.

I'd suggest you explore what gets executed on the server, and what gets executed on the client side. It will help your understanding when writing Views.

```
function CreateCategoryList() 
{
    var limit = @(Model.CategoriesCount.ToString());
    var clientSideArray = JSON.parse('@(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.CategoryList))');

    for (i=0; i<limit; i++)
    {
        var category = '<div class="CategoryItem">' + clientSideArray[i] + '</div>';                
        $("#CategoriesPopup").append(category);
    }
    alert($(".CategoryItem:first").text());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this is exactly what I need. But there is one problem. The string `var clientSideArray = JSON.Parse('@(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.CategoryList))');` makes my code unexecutable. I can see in console error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function". How to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, it will be on the `JSON.Parse`. it needs to be `JSON.parse`, lower case `p`. Note, to use `JSON.parse` in old browsers you need to include a library (such as json2.js)

Comment: It didn't solve the entire problem. Now I get "Unexpected token &" error. I also noticed, that string to parse contains &quot instead of normal quots(""). Maybe I should to prevent " -> &quot  convertion. But how?

Comment: Solved by myself. It is required to use @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.CategoryList)).